# MISRA-C 2012 - Rule 9.1 typedef struct

Tags: c, misra

```
typedef struct
{
  //data

}solve;
```

Declaration variable **help** without initializer

```
void solution (void)
{
solve help;
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Sharon, what is the problem?

Comment: So, "help" is a typedef struct variable, ya? It says, help is without initializer. How do I solve it?

Comment: Add an initializer.  In case of doubt, `= { 0 };` should work.  It isn't complete, but it does cause the variable to be initialized to zeros.

Comment: Rule 9.1 is simply about: don't use local variables before you have initialized them. If that is your problem, then the solution is kind of obvious, yes?

Comment: You can as well explicitly assign values to the structure's members. Your [mre] is too minimal, because we don't see where `help` is used.

Comment: = {0}; worked. I have another question, how do I initialize a char variable?

Comment: Simply `char uhhh = 0;`